# SharePoint 2010: What is the difference between backing up a Site Collection and exporting a Site Collection?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, backup, export, restore

Lectori salutem,

I am reading into backup and restore operations in SharePoint 2010. I have noticed that in Central Administration > Backup and Restore > Granular Backup there is the possibility to backup a site collection and to export a site collection.

Powershell commands are:

- Backup a site collection:

  [Backup-SPSite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607901%28v=office.14%29.aspx) -Identity  -Path  [Force] [-NoSiteLock] [-UseSqlSnapshot] [-Verbose]
- Export a site collection:

  [Export-SPWeb](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607895%28v=office.14%29.aspx) -Identity  -Path  [-ItemUrl ] [-IncludeUserSecurity] [-IncludeVersions] [-NoFileCompression] [-GradualDelete] [-Verbose]

> What is the difference between performing a backup and performing an export?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Backup-SPSite**  is generally used when you want to replicate the entire site collection (including all subsites) to an existing web application.

**Export-SPWeb** is generally used  when you want to replicate just a single subsite to an existing site collection.

Also below links are worth to read for other major differences:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yvan_duhamel/archive/2009/05/18/some-key-differences-between-stsadm-export-and-backup-operations.aspx

http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2009/05/27/limitations-of-stsadm-o-export-import-related-to-publishing-sites.aspx

Answer (score 5):

There is just a subtle difference:

- Workflows are included when you use the Backup-SPSite cmdlet.
- If you backup a root web of a site collection the site collection recycle bin will obviously not be included.

Answer (score 3):

Making a **backup** of the site collection is best used when you need to **restore** it on the **same environment**

It's *nearly* like a content database backup.

**Exporting** a site collection will allow you to **import** it on a different environment. It's working in a similar fashion than content deployment jobs. It will include in an environment agnostic way all the assets for to allow you to import it on a different farm.

*In short : if you're working in single environment (or cloned environment) backup & restore will do the trick. If you need to move site collection between environments, export & import are better suited.*

Answer (score 2):

The difference is they are two different objects, so two different commands for two different purposes.  You are mixing terminologies.  Look at the description of `Export-SPWeb` in your link ("Exports a **site, list, or library**").  You aren't exporting a site collection...you are exporting a site in your case.  A site collection and site are different.  A site collection is, as the name implies, a collection of sites.  A site resides within a site collection.  So `Backup-SPSite` backs up a site collection, which would include all sites within the site collection.  `Export-SPWeb` exports a site, not a site collection.  The object type on a site is web, thus `Export-SPWeb`.

Comment: not a correct answer

Comment: What is not correct about it?  I think you are misunderstanding the SharePoint object model, which is common.  I've been doing SharePoint since version 2003, I think I've got this simple thing at least. ;)