# Sharepoint 2010 site collection back up content only no permissions required

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

Ive a requirement to back up a site collection from dev environment and use it to provisivion a an exact copy as a new site collection in UAT.  I understand that we can use the following PowerShell command

```
Backup-SpSite
```

however in addition i need the site collection back up to contain only content and NO permission settings. wondered if anyone may know if there is a powershell command which allows this or a simple alternative to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are looking for is Export / Import. There is a switch `-IncludeUserSecurity` that can achieve your objective.

Read more here
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee428301.aspx
http://sharepointsolution2010.blogspot.sg/2011/09/import-and-export-sites-on-sharepoint.html
[SharePoint 2010: What is the difference between backing up a Site Collection and exporting a Site Collection?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/62152/sharepoint-2010-what-is-the-difference-between-backing-up-a-site-collection-and)

Hope this helps