# Export vs Backup

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, backup, export

What's major difference between export and backup and when to use backup and when i must use export?
When I was working with backup,I found export and backup have ability to save your current data.But there must be some difference between them.

Comment: Is it regarding site backup and export

Comment: I used for a site and list

Answer (score 1):

Both are for to backup the content in sharePoint,however the backup done through content db will restore the exact instance you have taken backup of whereas the export will create a new instance of the content. Means from export the siteID,ListID all changes and backup through content db the id's remains the same

[You may also refer the link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/yvan_duhamel/2009/05/18/some-key-differences-between-stsadm-export-and-backup-operations/)

Answer (score 0):

After consoluting with our partners I found following difference:
1-Export gets data from SharePoint and backup gets data from Database
2-Export is cross-version but backup works only in same version
I hope this helps :)

Comment: If you use export, test to be sure you can import. I have used export and import to copy sites and occasionally I cannot import a site I exported: It gets errors. I recall one site where this happened and when I looked at the site with SharePoint Designer, there were documents that were uploaded (or maybe attached) that were sitting in he site outside of document libraries. I could see them in the tree in the All Files view. Once I deleted those, I could then export and import. Strange.

Answer (score 0):

**Backup-SPSite** is generally used when you want to replicate the entire site collection (including all subsites) to an existing web application.

**Export-SPWeb** is generally used when you want to replicate just a single subsite to an existing site collection.

Also below links are worth to read for other major differences:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yvan_duhamel/archive/2009/05/18/some-key-differences-between-stsadm-export-and-backup-operations.aspx

http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2009/05/27/limitations-of-stsadm-o-export-import-related-to-publishing-sites.aspx

**Similar Question:** [SharePoint 2010: What is the difference between backing up a Site Collection and exporting a Site Collection?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/62152/sharepoint-2010-what-is-the-difference-between-backing-up-a-site-collection-and)